# In photoelectric experiment, the frequency of incident light changes from red to blue while keeping the energy per unit area per unit time constant

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Since I couldn't write the complete question in title: Effect of this change on saturation photocurrent?
I had reasoned that since saturation photocurrent depends on intensity of incident light which is given to be constant (energy per unit area and per unit time is constant).But the answer says that Saturation photocurrent for blue light is smaller than the one for red light.

What is incorrect in my reasoning?

[image]

Comment: May be they have given wrong answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intensity as defined is $\frac{energy}{area×time}$ .

Now in terms of photons , intensity of light can be written as

$I = nhf$ , for unit area and unit time.

From this equation

$n = \frac{I}{hf}$

Here $n$ is the number of photons released.

Keeping $I$ constant ( i.e. keeping the same unit area and for the same unit time)  in this equation and increasing $f$ (I.e. changing the colour of light from red to blue) will ultimately lead to a decrease in the number of photons being released.

This decrease in number of photons causes a decrease in the number of photoelectrons being emitted and hence the **saturation current drops** .

Hope it helps ☺️.